# computing sum of all cases in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here i want to return the sum of all cases. My requirement is to know whether particular product had the sales in last 10 weeks. For each week im returning either 1 when it had sales in a week or 0 when dont have any sales. So, if one product had sales in all last 10 weeks , i have to return 10 irrespective of number of sales. But using below query , im getting number of sales.

select Query:

```
SELECT PartNo 
      , sum(CASE WHEN DocDate BETWEEN "2017-01-26" AND "2017-02-01" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN DocDate BETWEEN "2017-02-02" AND "2017-02-08" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Qty1 
  FROM (`tbl_sales2`) 
 GROUP 
    BY `PartNo` 
 ORDER 
    BY `Qty1` DESC;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+------+
| PartNo      | Qty1 |
+-------------+------+
| 09343M05068 |    6 |
| 09343M05069 |    3 |
| 09343M05070 |    2 |
+-------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expected Result :

```
+-------------+------+
| PartNo      | Qty1 |
+-------------+------+
| 09343M05068 |    2 |
| 09343M05069 |    2 |
| 09343M05070 |    1 |
+-------------+------+
```

Table Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_sales2` (
`SaleId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`DocDate` date NOT NULL,
`PartNo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`SaleId`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Sample Data :

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_sales2` (`SaleId`, `DocDate`, `PartNo`) VALUES
('1', '2017-01-26', '09343M05068'),
('2', '2017-01-27', '09343M05068'),
('3', '2017-01-28', '09343M05068'),
('4', '2017-01-29', '09343M05068'),
('5', '2017-01-28', '09343M05069'),
('6', '2017-01-29', '09343M05069'),
('7', '2017-02-02', '09343M05068'),
('8', '2017-02-03', '09343M05068'),
('9', '2017-02-02', '09343M05069'),
('10', '2017-02-02', '09343M05070'),
('11', '2017-02-02', '09343M05070');
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `between '2017-01-26' and '2017-02-08'` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAX` instead of `SUM` to get 1 if there is atleast on row within given date range for that `PartNo`:

```
select PartNo,
    max(case when DocDate between '2017-01-26'
                    and '2017-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) 
    + max(case when DocDate between '2017-02-02'
                    and '2017-02-08' then 1 else 0 end) as Qty1
from `tbl_sales2`
group by `PartNo`
order by `Qty1` desc;
```

Produces:

```
PartNo      Qty1
09343M05068 2
09343M05069 2
09343M05070 1
```